How to enforce the condition of at most one element of a certain enumType in an array in json schema
I have this problem where I have a json schema similar to
{
    "$schema" : "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type" : "object",
    "title" : "salad",
    "properties":
     {
         "fruits" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "classpath:schema/fruit.json"
            }
      }
}

and this is the fruit json
{
    "$schema" : "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type" : "object",
    "title" : "fruit",
    "properties":
     {
         "fruitType" : {
            "enum": [
                "bitter",
                "tangy",
                "sweet",
                "sour"
              ]
        }
     }
}

How do i ensure at most one fruit of each type, i.e, bitter, sweet... is in the salad.
I have tried going through the documentation and various json schema forums, I want to know if this is even possible with the current scope of json schema and get a solution if it is indeed possible.

If fruitType is the only property you'll have in the items, then probably adding uniqueItems: true to the array schema will do the trick.
The trouble with uniqueItems, though, is it looks at the item in its entirety, not just individual properties.  To do that, you need something like uniqueKeys from my Array Extensions vocab.  It's only supported in .Net as far as I'm aware, but if your validator supports custom keywords, maybe you can implement it yourself.

Thanks, unfortunately fruitType is not the only property. I will extend my validator for this use case.

You need the contains and maxContains keywords, but you don't have maxContains in draft-07. maxContains was added in 2019-09. Unfortunately, there is no way to emulate maxContains in draft-07. Here's how it would be expressed in a dialect that has maxContains.
"allOf": [
  {
    "contains": {
      "properties": {
        "fruitType": { "const": "bitter" }
      },
      "required": ["fruitType"]
    },
    "maxContains": 1
  },
  {
    "contains": {
      "properties": {
        "fruitType": { "const": "tangy" }
      },
      "required": ["fruitType"]
    },
    "maxContains": 1
  },
  { ... same for sweet ... },
  { ... same for sour ... }
]

